# Inequality with some integral$\frac{ 1}{(1+|x|)^n}$ over ball

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

I'm struggling to prove this inequality.

> Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\left|x\right|\ge10$ and $t>\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}$, prove
>   that 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{m(B\left(x,t\right))}\int_{B\left(x,t\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\left|y\right|\right)^{n}}dy\le C_n\frac{\log t}{t^{n}},
> $$
>   where $B\left(x,t\right)$ is a ball centered at $x$ with radius
>   $t$ and $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C_n$ is a constant depending only on the dimension $n$.

I got this result when $n=1$, but I fail to obtain higher dimensional result.

This inequality can be found in R. Coifmann, "compensated compactness in Hardy space"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This was really easy result by considering antiderivative of $r^{n-1}/(1+r^n)$.